# How to kill process from within subshell

Tags: bash, shell, cat, read

I have a bash function like this:

```
listen_to_thing(){

    cat /tmp/srv-output | while read line; do
      echo "catted: $line"
      if [[ "$line" == 'EOF' ]]; then
         exit 0;  ## I want to exit out of the function upon this event
      fi
    done;

}
```

when I get a keyword, I want to exit from the cat process and finish the bash function. I can exit out of the bash func with a SIGINT from the command line, but is there a way to exit out of the bash func programmatically from within the read loop?

Comment: I don't understand how it relates to your title, but it looks like you want to `return` rather than `exit`

Comment: nah the `while read` creates an implicit subshell, return doesn't mean anything in there, only exit does

Comment: ... only because of the UUoC

Comment: i don't know what UUoC means nor do I think most people do..link?

Comment: maybe you mean I could do `for line of $(cat /tmp/srv-output); do`

Comment: @AlexanderMills UUOC: useless use of `cat`: don't `cat FILE |`, just provide the file to the input of the `while` loop: `...done <FILE` & use `return` not `exit`

Comment: If you *must* pipe into a `while` loop for some reason, then you can `break` from the loop when your condition is met - after which your function will `return` in the usual way (when control reaches the end of the function)

Answer (score 1):

Don't `cat` the file and all is well:

```bsh
listen_to_thing() {
    while read line; do
        echo "read: $line"
        case "$line" in
            EOF) return 0 ;;    # Return out of the function upon this event
        esac
    done </tmp/srv-output
}
```

- In case you wanted to differentiate between a file with a `$line` containing `EOF` and a file that had just ended, you could return a non-zero status

Answer (score 0):

I think this works well from my testing:

```
listen_to_thing(){

      (
       export kill_this="$BASHPID"
       cat /tmp/srv-output | while read line; do
          echo "catted: $line"
          if [[ "$line" == 'EOF' ]]; then
             kill -9 "$kill_this"
             exit 0;
          fi
        done;
      )

}
```

where $BASHPID is the PID of the current process context.

Comment: Why not just like .. `break` out of the loop? also, is your subshell so stubborn that it needs a `kill -9`? (obligate numeric, because `kill -KILL` is not l33t enough) Or has `kill -9` become a second nature, just like `sudo` everything?